# SqlDependency - "Login failed for user 'sa'."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5, sqldependency

I am trying to subscribe to Query Notification using SqlDependency. My application is written in c# and I am using Entity Framework 5.0 to connect and perform CRUD operations.
I have enabled SERVICE BROKER on the database.

I am using 'sa' account so no permissions need to be granted, however as it is not working I tried creating another user and granted all necessary permissions. It still does not work.

I have been using the same code for a while, it always worked for me. Even now I have a test database on the same server to which I can subscribe for the notification. However for this particular database it does not work.

I can connect to the database and perform CRUD. But when I try to subscribe to Query Notification it throws the following exception

> "Login failed for user 'sa'."
>   (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)  Exception Message = "Login failed
>   for user 'sa'.", Exception Type =
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException", Exception WinRT Data = null

Not sure what the 'WinRT' is at the end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry mate, but your question is written badly, show some code ...

Comment: What code would you like to see? As I said the same c# code works for another database in the same server. So I guess I will need help with the sql server rather than on the c# application. And I am using 'sa' account ot login, therefore there was no need to grant any permission on Sql server. I hope I have explained.

Comment: My connection string ------- <add name="tuEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/tuModel.csdl|res://*/tuModel.ssdl|res://*/tuModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server;initial catalog=tu;user id=sa;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding 'persist security info=True' to the connection string. It is strange that the other database was working without this.